# How to apply multiple custom functions to the same column without using apply every time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three functions:

```
def replace_date(x):
    pass

def replace_name(x):
    pass

def replace_occupation(x):
    pass
```

They need to be applied to each row in a specific column. So far I write the code

```
df['mod'] = df['info'].apply(lambda row: replace_date(row)).apply(lambda row: replace_name(row)).apply(lambda row: replace_occupation(row)).apply(lambda row: re.sub(' +', ' ', row))
```

The last one I did not yet put into a separate function but I want to get rid of the three `apply`-s and write it in a nicer and more compact way.

Comment: `.apply(lambda row: re.sub(' +', ' ', replace_occupation(replace_name(replace_date(row)))))` doesn't work?

Comment: Please post your full functions. Maybe there are better ways to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```py
df['mod'] = df['info'].apply(lambda row: re.sub(' +', ' ', replace_occupation(replace_name(replace_date(row)))))
```

It's one `apply()` although slightly less readable due to the `re.sub(' +', ' ', row)` in the end.

More generally, it is

```py
df['col'].apply(lambda row: h(f(g(row))))
```

for some functions `f()`, `g()`, and `h()`.